Tag removal suggestions (or does the system auto-delete abandoned tags?)
I would herewith like to suggest the removal of the following, three tags:

online – reason: too broad (and not really indicating a cryptographic area either).
protocols – reason: too broad (more specific tags exist… protocol-design and protocol-analysis).
bouncycastle – reason: might attract off-topic questions about implementation (see help center).

Edit
I just noticed (a day later) that those tags are gone from the tag-list. This makes me realize I probably missed something (and might be hitting a facepalm soon).
Each of those tags were used by 1 or 2 questions, which I edited to retag them using better-fitting tags. This resulted in the fact that there were no questions left that pointed to the tags I mentioned above.
Could it be that a tag is automatically deleted when there are no questions left that use it? Or, is this a misinterpretation and someone already killed those tags without leaving a note here (less likely)?
I'm asking to be sure I'm not posting superfluous stuff about things the system might be taking care of all by itself already…
Nota bene: 
I adapted the title to reflect the edit, as it might be useful (for future reference) to know if the system does this automatically.

Yes, I believe tags that are not used are eventually purged.

Thank you for the edits.
Tags are automatically removed when no question uses them. This is done by a daily batch job, so wait 24 hours.
Additionally, there is a completely separate mechanism that hard-deletes tags that are 6 months old and used by a single question, without creating an entry in the question's revision history. Tags that have a tag wiki are exempt.

"Tags that have a tag wiki are exempt" That's different from what I remember. Did they add that exemption?

@CodesInChaos Yes, about a year back.
